# How to set custom headers?

Tags: lyx, fancyhdr

Having some experience with Latex, I'm now using LyX seriously for the first time. Since I need to set custom headers, I have enabled the Custom Header/Footerlines module and set the page layout to fancy. The result is a horizontal line at the top of each page. Where to enter the header's actual content?

Comment: See also the answer to a related question by @Werner: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281059/12212

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use LyX's layout menu. After you have the module enabled click on the upper-left box (which probably currently says `Standard`). A useful keyboard shortcut for this is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, space. Then start typing "Header" and it will filter it for you.

[image: LyX's layout menu]

Comment: What Document class is this? IEEE Transactions does not have this option.

Comment: @zygimantus did you follow the instructions? Specifically, did you see the part "After you have the module enabled". Do you have the module enabled?

Comment: I am not sure how to enable it.

Comment: @zygimantus OK, then that is the question to ask. If you ever see instructions and do not understand them, ask for help on the first instruction that you do not understand. To add the module go to Document > Settings > Modules, click on "Custom Header/Footlines" and click "Add".

Comment: The module has different names in different languages... In Ukrainian, for example, it is listed as: "Нетипові рядки шапки/підвалу".