# How to add footer in Lyx when using IEEE Transactions class?

Tags: header-footer, lyx, ieeetran

How do I add a footer in LyX file when using IEEE Transactions class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110177/how-to-set-custom-headers/110188#110188 but Werner's alternate answer is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change the Document > Settings... > Page Layout and change the page style to fancy:

[image]

Then add to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble

```
\fancyfoot[L]{Left footer}
\fancyfoot[C]{Center footer}
\fancyfoot[R]{Right footer}

% Update \maketitle to change page style for first page
\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \oldmaketitle
  \thispagestyle{fancy}% Title page has fancy
}
```

[image]

The adjustment of `\maketitle` adds the footer to the first page, which has a different style based on the IEEE document class. If you don't want it, then you can just remove that part of the code.

Comment: Two questions: How to remove the top line? And why do I get the footer on all pages?

Comment: @zygimantus: To remove the top line (or header rule), add `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` to the preamble. You didn't specify where you want the footers to appear, so my solution suggests it to appear on *all* pages. Where do you want it?

Comment: I want the footer on the first page only.

Comment: @zygimantus: Okay, then change the page layout heading style back to "Default".

Comment: But then \fancyfoot is undefined!

Comment: @zygimantus: Change the page layout heading style to "fancy" and add `\pagestyle{headings}` at the end of the preamble.